# Info window not displaying on ng-click angularjs google map in android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-maps, cordova

I am trying to implement google map in android using this js fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/pc7Uu/. Everything works correctly except infowindow touch event.I t will works fine when running browser but not in android device.Here is the code that not working in phone.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'ng-click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });
```

`ng-click` is not working in phone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ng-click` event - it's directive.

But your fiddle seems ok. Try using also `tap` event if `click` does nothing.

It's difficult to use non-angular services in angular app because of `$digest` cycles not working on their own. Consider using dedicated service such as [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/).

Comment: Please specify whether you are able/not able to open infoWindow 1) on click on market 2) on click on link under the map